# Unable to register route in $di Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I am unable to register custom routes in phalcon. I have no idea what is the problem.

```
   $di['router'] = function () {
        return require __DIR__ . '/config/routes.php';
    };
```

in routes file i have

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

//$router->setUriSource(Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);

  $router->add('/confirm/{code}/{email}', array(
    'controller' => 'user_control',
    'action' => 'confirmEmail'
 ));

 /*$router->add('/reset-password/{code}/{email}', array(
    'controller' => 'user_control',
     'action' => 'resetPassword'
    ));*/

 return $router;
```

When i go to /confirm/32sadfasdfwef/www@gmail.com

i am getting

```
  Ilm\Frontend\Controllers\ConfirmController handler class cannot be loaded
```

Its multi module application.

```
And if i do die() in $di['router'] it does not do anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't need the double `return`. You have one in your include and one in your service closure. Either remove it from the routes.php and do this:

```
$di['router'] = function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/config/routes.php';
    return $router;
};
```

Or leave it there and do this:

```
$di['router'] = function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/config/routes.php';
};
```

The first option feels more natural, IMO. If it's a multi-module app, you also need to specify the module in your routes, have a look [here](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/18/how-to-work-with-routing-in-multimodule-applications-#C82).

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action/:params', array(
    'module' => "frontend",
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3
))->setName('front-full');
```